# Canvas arrowheads by clicking

Tags: html, css

There is a problem making arrowheads by clicking. Thank you
link Code

```
> https://jsfiddle.net/liptonkingza/bxtup8nv/2/
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please could you describe some more what the problem is as the code you give seems to work as far as it goes - that is it just draws lines. What more is expected? Are you wanting lines to automatically join up some way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I dont know that where is wrong.

```js
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "blue",
        y = 3;
    
    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;
    
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    }
 
    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
   
    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
#can {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
    <p>
        Below you can draw :
    </p>
    <canvas id="can" width="750" height="1050" style="position:absolute;"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, he stated he wanted arrowheads.